# What is causing this issue: "Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;."

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, vue-test-utils, mocha-webpack

In the VueJs web application, we have written more than 500 unit test-cases(in all modules) using vue-test-utils and mocha-webpack, using nyc for coverage reports. 
Consider each module in one directory. When I run test-cases for a particular module, report gets generated successfully with test-case results(pass or fail). But running all test-cases in one go(by setting the path in package.json), all test-cases doesn't execute and throws following error:

**Timeout of 100000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.**

I have seen similar questions that suggest using async await in code or increasing the timeout to resolve this, but why test-cases get executes when I run for a particular module and throws above error when I run for the whole project.

I have tried setting --timeout 100000 in package.json and it helped for large number of test-cases, but while running all(more than 500) unit test-cases again It throws the same error.
I think this has to do with the number of test-cases.

What is causing this issue and How to resolve this so all test-cases runs successfully.?

**Edit**
If any code in unit-tests is causing this timeout issue, How to detect which testcase is causing this issue, because It seems not possible to detect the source of issue by looking at logs in command prompt. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. It's impossible to answer this without seeing test cases. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . In case tests contain something that can result in slower testing time when performed in batch (db, whatever), that's the problem. Otherwise it isn't.

Comment: To verify that the time is the issue why not try --timeout 1000000000 or something else that's ridiculisly high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many resolutions tried, came to a conclusion, that resolved above issue:

1. When we run test-cases, and there are dependency related warnings
   then It slows down test-cases and gives timeout issue. The
   resolution is to remove these warnings by mocking actions,
   mutations, getters and stubbing child components.
2. Adding NODE_OPTIONS: 'node --max_old_space_size=16384' in the
   configuration file will increase the NodeJS memory.This has improved
   performance of unit-tests.
3. Instead of using beforeEach, use before and after methods for
   mounting the components in wrapper. Also use destroy in after method
   to destroy the wrapper as follows:

```js
let wrapper;

before(() => {
  wrapper = mount('component_name', {
    ...
  })
});

after(() => {
  wrapper.destroy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let wrapper;

before(() => {
  wrapper = mount('component_name', {
    ...
  })
});

after(() => {
  wrapper.destroy();
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.